# Convert Milliseconds to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, calendar

Input:-

```
milliSecond = '1519073776000';
```

Output:-

```
Date = "2018-02-20 02:26:16";
```

Convert Millisecond Date into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s`s format

Comment: that would be the Date object you're looking for - here, let me google that for you - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date (is it exam time?)

Comment: I recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for anything time-related. `moment(1519073776000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two steps to your question.

Step 1: Get date from milliseconds.

This can easily be done by calling `new Date(MILLISECONDS_AS_NUMBER);`.

Step 2: Format a date string from the Date object.

This is a little more complicated, as there are no default method for doing this.

The best method is to create a function that takes a format string and a date and simply stack `format.replace(token, Date.key)` calls.

Here is an implementation of the above steps:

```js
function toDate(date) {
  if (date === void 0) {
    return new Date(0);
  }
  if (isDate(date)) {
    return date;
  } else {
    return new Date(parseFloat(date.toString()));
  }
}

function isDate(date) {
  return (date instanceof Date);
}

function format(date, format) {
  var d = toDate(date);

  return format
    .replace(/Y/gm, d.getFullYear().toString())
    .replace(/m/gm, ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2))
    .replace(/d/gm, ('0' + (d.getDate() + 1)).substr(-2))
    .replace(/H/gm, ('0' + (d.getHours() + 0)).substr(-2))
    .replace(/i/gm, ('0' + (d.getMinutes() + 0)).substr(-2))
    .replace(/s/gm, ('0' + (d.getSeconds() + 0)).substr(-2))
    .replace(/v/gm, ('0000' + (d.getMilliseconds() % 1000)).substr(-3));
}
//TEST
var ms = '1519073776000';
var dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s.v";
var formatted = format(ms, dateFormat);
console.log(formatted);
```

Alternatively you could opt-out of all this and use a library like [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) to handle this.

Comment: Date-Time return is wrong
for - 1519073776000
it should be - 2018-02-20 02:26:16

Comment: @ShubhamGhormade I used UTC time before which always returned GMT+0 time. This could have given you a different time than expected, so i changed it to accommodate the local timezone. This will also mean that the date is always interpreted relative to the clients local time.

Comment: Thank You Emil S. Jorgensen

Comment: The above code is a great way of converting a date to any string format although it does have an error. It correctly adds 1 to month as month in javascript is 0 index (Jan = 0 Dec = 11) but for some reason (typo maybe) it is also adding 1 to the date which is should not. So the date part of the replace should be: .replace(/d/gm, ('0' + (d.getDate() + 0)).substr(-2))